# plot connecting lines between dots issue

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, line

Trying to fit a sin function using curve_fit to some points here. When plotting both the fit and the points, I get something I have no idea how to explain, so I better post some images.

Using the following code line yields:

```
plt.plot(phase_min, sinusoidal_function(phase_min, *popt), '.', lw=3)
```

[image]

Using the line style '-', I get:

[image]

How can I just have a damn line connecting each adjacent dot, not all the dots in between?

Comment: Have you sorted `phase_min`?

Comment: I don't think I need to. phase_min follows from phase, which is sorted. I guess it inherits the behavior? (Py beginner here)

Comment: I don't think it's already sorted. You can print it out and check. Also after curve fitting, you don't need to plot the fitted curve against the original variable values, you should make the x values for the range you want to plot. Try something like this: `x=np.arange(0, 1, 0.001), y=sinusoidal_function(x, *popt), plt.plot(x,y)`

Comment: @LongwenOu Just verified that it was not sorted. After sorting, I get something weird, as you can see here: http://imgur.com/a/yrEbx

Comment: @LongwenOu That does indeed solve the problem, but I don't understand how or why it does that.

Comment: I think your fitting process is fine. You just need to redo the plotting process using the code I showed you before.

Answer (score 3):

When you plot a line in `matplotlib`, it automatically connects the points in the same order as they are provided. See the example below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1,3,2], [1,2,3])
```

[image]

Your problem is that your `phase_min` is not sorted and `matplotlib` is trying to connect your data points in order. Actually since you already got the fitted function, you don't need to use the original data to plot the function. You can just define the data points you want to plot the line as below. In this way you can have as many data points as you want to make the plot, so the line will be more smooth than if you make the plots using your original data points.

```
x=np.arange(0, 1, 0.001)
y=sinusoidal_function(x, *popt)
plt.plot(x,y)
```

Comment: Oh, now I see :) This makes sense. The thing that I don't understand is why if I did sort phase_min, that I still get weird results. This should have taken care of the point to point connections, and everything should be in order. Am I wrong?

Comment: @nyw Are you sorting `phase_min` before or after the fitting process? If you are sorting before fitting, then you have to make sure that the correspondence between `phase_min` and your `y` values remain unchanged. So you should only sort after the fitting process, before making the plot. Still, the method showed above should be preferred.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `np.argsort`:

```
order = np.argsort(x)
xsorted = x[order]
ysorted = y[order]
```

where `x` and`y` are the coordinates of your orange dots.

Comment: I am not sure I understand. Sorting phase_min gives me something weird
http://imgur.com/a/yrEbx

Comment: The trick is _rearranging_ `x` and `y` together. If you only sort one of the two you are separating coordinate pairs and something weird is expected. Try sorting `phase_min` and applying yout sinusoidal function to the sorted `phase_min` and use the sorted things for both data arguments in the plot.

Comment: I did just that using phase_min.sort(), and I get the plot in the link above your comment.

Comment: Maybe you got the colours mixed up? I think the green stuff is the sinusoidal and the orange things are what is blue in the other plots? then it would just be a matter of scaling. Could that be?

Comment: I think that is the case. I got lost into trying to figure this out and I believe I have a big mess over here :)